# Download File in vb.net desktop Application

Tags: vb.net, desktop-application, download

Can anyone help me on how can I download file form another computer and save it to my computer..

Comment: Can you give more details please? Are you writing this and want to deploy it so that other's can download it?

Comment: What protocol are you using? Will you be downloading from a webserver, or something from a local network using a network share?

Comment: I used to download files in local networks. Yes I want to write the code to download files from another host..

Comment: Any idea on how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure exactly what you want to download or where from, but I'm guessing that what you're looking for is to download something from a website to a local file and if so, look at `WebClient.DownloadFile`. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadfile%28VS.80%29.aspx for more info.

Otherwise, if you mean just copying files in the local network, then you can just use `File.Copy`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.copy.aspx

Comment: Follow up question:

I have used your link for me to copy the files..

The question is how can I choose the location where to save the files to be copy.. The code in the link is a hard coded link (where to copy the file)..

My first idea is to use the OpenFileDialog tools to locate the folder path where to copy the files but I fail to do that..

Any idea on how can I do it? Hoping for your feedback

Comment: Wrong way around, since you want a path for where to write the file, you should be using SaveFileDialog.

Comment: See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx

Comment: @Mark Just so you know - if this answer solved your problem, you should click on the big tick next to the answer. This "accepts" it as the solution and gives `ho1` some points. It's the polite thing to do around here.

Comment: @Mark: As MarkJ and ho1 both said, you really should accept answers when given. 0 for 13 is pretty terrible. Please be more considerate if you want people to answer your questions. As for me, I found ho1's answer very helpful, so thank you ho1 :)